# How to compare 2 different classes implementing same interface for equality?

Tags: c#, interface

```
public interface IMyType{
    int Val1 {get; set;}
    int Val2 {get; set;}
}


public class ImplA : IMyType{
    public int Val1 {get; set;}
    public int Val2 {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}
    
}

public class ImplB : IMyType{
    public int Val1 {get; set;}
    public int Val2 {get; set;}
    public int Age {get; set;}
    
}

List<IMyType> myTypes = new List<IMyType>();
myTypes.Add(new ImplA(){ Val1 = 100, Val2 = 200, Name ="John"});
myTypes.Add(new ImplA(){ Val1 = 500, Val2 = 600, Name ="Steve"});

IMyType t = new ImplB(){ Val1 = 100, Val2 = 200, Age =30});

bool exists = myTypes.Contains(t); //returns false because types are different
```

It makes sense that it compares the implementation types for equality and results in 'false' but is there a way to do equality and contains such that it ignores the implementation types and only compares the interface properties for equality? (in this example it would return true since Val1 and Val2 are equal)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can't override a custom `Equals` on your types, you can always define a custom Equality Comparer for the interface type.

```cs
using System:
using System.Collections.Generic;

// implements IEqualityComparer<IMyType> 
// it's recommended to derive from EqualityComparer<T>
public class MyTypeComparer : EqualityComparer<IMyType>
{
   public override int GetHashCode(IMyType obj){
      return HashCode.Combine(obj.Val1, obj.Val2);
      // or if System.HashCode is unavailable, something like
      // return 37 ^ obj.Val1 ^ obj.Val2;
   } 
   public override bool Equals(IMyType a, IMyType b) {
      if (ReferenceEquals(a, b)) return true;
      if (a is null || b is null) return false;
      return a.Val1 == b.Val1 && a.Val2 == b.Val2;
   } 
}
```

Then use the [`Enumerable.Contains`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.contains?view=net-5.0#System_Linq_Enumerable_Contains__1_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0____0_System_Collections_Generic_IEqualityComparer___0__) extension method that accepts an `IEqualityComparer<T>` rather than `List<T>.Contains`

```cs
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;

var myTypes = new List<IMyType>();
myTypes.Add(new ImplA(){ Val1 = 100, Val2 = 200, Name = "John"});
myTypes.Add(new ImplA(){ Val1 = 500, Val2 = 600, Name = "Steve"});

IMyType t = new ImplB(){ Val1 = 100, Val2 = 200, Age = 30 };
bool exists = myTypes.Contains(t, new MyTypeComparer());

Console.WriteLine(exists); // true
```

See this [SharpLab](https://sharplab.io/#v2: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=) for an example.

Answer (score 1):

> returns false because types are different

No, it returns `false` because it's a new instance. Test this with the following:

```
myTypes.Add(new ImplA(){ Val1 = 100, Val2 = 200, Name ="John"});
bool exists = myTypes.Contains(new ImplA(){ Val1 = 100, Val2 = 200, Name ="John"});
```

That will still return `false` as written.

Why is that? Because you didn't override the default `object.Equals(object)` virtual method in either of your types, and the default implementation calls `object.ReferenceEquals`, which returns whether the two objects have the same reference, ie if they're literally the same instance.

From what I understand, you want to override `object.Equals` like this:

```
public class ImplA : IMyType
{
    public int Val1 {get; set;}
    public int Val2 {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}

    public override bool Equals(object obj) =>
        obj is ImplA objA ? (Val1, Val2, Name) == (objA.Val1, objA.Val2, objA.Name)
        : obj is IMyType objI ? (Val1, Val2) == (objI.Val1, objI.Val2)
        : false;
}
```

Comment: Nope, unfortunately its not an option to implement Equals in the Impl classes

Comment: @CaiusJard The answer produces incorrect output for the example provided (in addition to not actually solving the problem described in the general case), in addition to making statements that simply aren't true.  It's both incorrect, and not useful.

Comment: Those are quite the big words there, what exactly is incorrect?

Answer (score -1):

I fully support Blindy's answer for the corrections to the misapprehensions about how objects are compared (by memory address, absent any override of Equals/GetHashCode) it makes, and it's how I would have proposed working.

You said in a comment that you cannot override Equals for ImplX / IMyType, which is surprising but if it's a constraint that must be suffered then you can alter the way you check for whether the list contains a matching item:

> is there a way to do equality and contains such that it ignores the implementation types and only compares the interface properties for equality? (in this example it would return true since Val1 and Val2 are equal)

It depends what you mean by "contains". If you mean exactly and specifically using `Contains(T)`, without being able to override Equals for the items, then No unless you want to extend the list and override Contains instead.. But LINQ's Any(=>) can tell you if a list contains an item, and because it's all IMyType regardless of the actual implementation, you can do this:

```
IMyType t = new ImplB(){ Val1 = 100, Val2 = 200, Age =30});
bool exists = myTypes.Any(i => i.Val1 == t.Val1 && i.Val2 == t.Val2);
```

You could bake this into an inherited list as an override to Contains too, if you like..

Comment: I don't know why someone downvoted. This is the most obvious and easiest way to compare items based on a subset of their properties, which is the OP's requirement. Overriding `Equals` and implementing a `IEqualityComparer` will both compile and work, I guess, but are a poor (and confusing) fit, semantically. The elements aren't really equal if they only match on two of their three properties.

Answer (score -2):

yes. You can use Reflection.
There are better methods that this but you can take it as sample.

```
    public static bool Compare(IMyType a, IMyType b)
    {
        IList<PropertyInfo> properties = typeof(IMyType).GetProperties().ToList();
        bool risposta = true;
        foreach (var property in properties)
        {
            if (!property.GetValue(a).Equals(property.GetValue(b)))
            {
                risposta = false;
            }
        }
        return risposta;
    }
```

Use this method for check if object are in list.

```
public static bool CheckIfExists(List<IMyType> list, IMyType newObj) {
        foreach (IMyType m in list) {
            if(Compare(m, newObj))
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

And add in List:

```
if (!CheckIfExists(myTypes, t)) {
            myTypes.Add(t);
        }
```